# How to get the first non zero / non null value and the last zero / non null value among multiple columns using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is how the data looks, here the

```
"ID"    "ACTIVE"    "SERVICEID" "MONTH" "D1"    "D2"    "D3"    "D4"    "D5"    "D6"    "D7"    "D8"    "D9"    "D10"   "D11"   "D12"   "D13"   "D14"   "D15"   "D16"   "D17"   "D18"   "D19"   "D20"   "D21"   "D22"   "D23"   "D24"   "D25"   "D26"   "D27"   "D28"   "D29"   "D30"   "D31"   
352917  1   "FEUSA0001U"    199603                                              24.48   23.76   24.24   24.82           24.84   25.24   25  25  25.5            25.76   25.88   25.62   25.24   25.62               
353793  1   "FEUSA00024"    199603                                              14.92   14.77   14.8    14.78           14.57   14.75   14.75   14.75   14.75           14.75   14.75   14.56   14.56   14.69               
377994  1   "FEUSA0001X"    199603                                              59.16   58.84   59.12   59.92           59.72   60  60  61.52   61.24           61.76   61.76   62.24   62.24   62.76               
377737  1   "FEUSA00026"    199603                                                   9.89   9.9 10.01           10.01   10.12   10.12   10.25   10.25           10.25   10.25   10.25   10.25   10.25
```

So for the first record i need to get back First non zero / non null as D6 or 6 and for the last record non zero/ not null value should be D20 or 20.

Let me know if you need more information on this.

Here is the DDL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE "SERV" (
     "ID"           NUMBER,
     "ACTIVE"       NUMBER,
     "SERVICEID"    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
     "MONTH"        NUMBER(*,0),
     "D1"           NUMBER,
     "D2"           NUMBER,
     "D3"           NUMBER,
     "D4"           NUMBER,
     "D5"           NUMBER,
     "D6"           NUMBER,
     "D7"           NUMBER,
     "D8"           NUMBER,
     "D9"           NUMBER,
     "D10"          NUMBER,
     "D11"          NUMBER,
     "D12"          NUMBER,
     "D13"          NUMBER,
     "D14"          NUMBER,
     "D15"          NUMBER,
     "D16"          NUMBER,
     "D17"          NUMBER,
     "D18"          NUMBER,
     "D19"          NUMBER,
     "D20"          NUMBER,
     "D21"          NUMBER,
     "D22"          NUMBER,
     "D23"          NUMBER,
     "D24"          NUMBER,
     "D25"          NUMBER,
     "D26"          NUMBER,
     "D27"          NUMBER,
     "D28"          NUMBER,
     "D29"          NUMBER,
     "D30"          NUMBER,
     "D31"          NUMBER
)
```

DML sample records

```
Insert into SERV (ID,ACTIVE,SERVICEID,MONTH,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31) values (352917,1,'FEUSA0001U',199603,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,24.48,23.76,24.24,24.82,null,null,24.84,25.24,25,25,25.5,null,null,25.76,25.88,25.62,25.24,25.62,null,null);
Insert into SERV (ID,ACTIVE,SERVICEID,MONTH,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31) values (353793,1,'FEUSA00024',199603,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,14.92,14.77,14.8,14.78,null,null,14.57,14.75,14.75,14.75,14.75,null,null,14.75,14.75,14.56,14.56,14.69,null,null);
Insert into SERV (ID,ACTIVE,SERVICEID,MONTH,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31) values (377994,1,'FEUSA0001X',199603,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,59.16,58.84,59.12,59.92,null,null,59.72,60,60,61.52,61.24,null,null,61.76,61.76,62.24,62.24,62.76,null,null);
Insert into SERV (ID,ACTIVE,SERVICEID,MONTH,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31) values (377737,1,'FEUSA00026',199603,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,9.95,9.89,9.9,10.01,null,null,10.01,10.12,10.12,10.25,10.25,null,null,10.25,10.25,10.25,10.25,10.25,null,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very poor data format.  In general, having columns that are distinguished just by a number is a bad sign.  The better structure is one row per value, rather than one column.

You can do what you want using a giant case expression:

```
select s.*,
       (case when s.d1 <> 0 then s.d1
             when s.d2 <> 0 then s.d2
             . . .
             when s.d31 <> 0 then s.d31
        end) as first_flag
from serv s;
```

Comment: One advantage of the current arrangement (flawed as it is, and as you correctly point out) is that the result to this specific question can be obtained with a single scan of the table - no aggregation needed. Aggregation is an expensive operation. It would definitely be wrong to unpivot the data just to put it in the "proper arrangement" (losing the pre-grouped nature of the data in the process). What you wrote is the right way to do it, given the data is already presented in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT ID,
       ACTIVE,
       SERVICEID,
       MONTH,
       COALESCE(D1, D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31) FIRST_NOTNULL,
       COALESCE(D31, D30,D29,D28,D27,D26,D25,D24,D23,D22,D21,D20,D19,D18,D17,D16,D15,D14,D13,D12,D11,D10,D9,D8,D7,D6,D5,D4,D3,D2,D1) LAST_NOTNULL
  FROM SERV
```

Regards!

Comment: This is a good approach, but the issue is that the OP also wants to skip over zero, not only over NULL. That can be arranged: instead of D1 use `NULLIF(D1, 0)` in `COALESCE`. A pain in the butt, but perhaps still easier to write than Gordon's solution. However, Gordon's solution will likely be faster - fewer function calls.